# brainwallet.org Low Entropy Generation

Tags: coldstorage, brain-wallet

I was reading that brainwallet.org uses low-entropy RNGs, so any address generated using their website will be unsafe. I used their website to make a cold storage address last December, and so far no one's stolen anything from it. Is it worth it to make a new address on a more secure website? I've put a large amount of time into the current one; I memorized the first 2/3 of the private key and have the last third written down (most secure method in my opinion).

Comment: You should move them. Read this: http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/295las/35_of_my_btc_gone_pc_not_compromised/

Answer (score 1):

I used WarpWallet. I booted my computer into Linux, copied WarpWallet off my flash drive, ran it, put in my passcode (39 random hex digits that I've memorized), and I had my address. (I triple checked that the same passphrase always gave me the same private key, and all this time the computer was, of course, disconnected from the internet) I wrote down the public key on a piece of paper, then transferred all my old cold-storage bitcoin to it. https://blockchain.info/tx/13fd0f4ef557317871965f12d02e17069dc782d3dce9f2f44c4b751c3c856595